# Phone Gap App crashs in when in landscape mode

Tags: android, cordova, screen

I have built an app using phonegap 1.3 and jquery mobile. The problem that i am having is when I rotate the screen on my device (HTC Desire HD) it force closes the app.

I am using the setup instructions found on the Phonegap website.

Does anyone know of a fix for this please as I have tried fiddling with it but still to no change.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think changing your activity in Manifest.xml to this will help you

```
<activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".App" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
             <intent-filter> 
                 </intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you AndroidManifest.xml as for the configuration attribute set it to:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

In both activities.